# Strip tags (with tags inside attributes and nested tags) using javascript

Tags: javascript, strip-tags

What the fastest (in performance) way to strip strings from tags, most solution i've tried that uses regexp not resulting correct values for tags inside attributes (yes, i know it's wrong), example test case:

```
 var str = "<div data-content='yo! press this: <br/> <button type=\"button\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-disk\"></i> Save</button>' data-title='<div>this one for tooltips <div>seriously</div></div>'> this is the real content<div> with another nested</div></div>"
```

that should resulting:

```
 this is the real content with another nested
```

Comment: This is exactly why [THE PONY HE COMES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: How can you expect any regex to work properly with the input that is incorrect (has syntax errors)? Your attributes values are enclosed with `'` and they also consist of `'`.

Comment: @matewka my bad, forgot to change that one for this question..

Comment: why -1, does it not show research effort? does it not clear? does it not useful? -___-"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using innerText should be pretty fast:

```
var str = "<div data-content='yo! press this: <br/> <button type='button'><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-disk\"></i></button>' data-title='<div>this one for tooltips</div>'> this is the real content<div> with another nested</div></div>"; 
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = str;
var text = el.textContent || el.innerText;
alert(text);
```

Comment: +1, but keep in mind that it's not fully cross-browser. You should use `el.textContent || el.innerText`.